# How can I use a method to add a filter on a property in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to conditionally add a filter to particular dates in a query. There are common preconditions and the filter will be the same. Therefore I would like the common code to be in a method which can perform these checks and then have the consumer pass in the property which the filter should be applied to (could be applied to multiple).

Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
var query = dbContext.Documents.AsQueryable();

query = FilterDocumentsByDate(query, x => x.CreatedDate);
query = FilterDocumentsByDate(query, x => x.SubmittedDate);

private IQueryable<Document> FilterDocumentsByDate(IQueryable<Document> query, Func<Document, DateTime> propertyToSearch)
{
    query = query.Where(x => propertyToSearch(x).Year > 2000);
    return query;
}
```

When I look at the query in SQL profiler, I can see that the query is missing the WHERE clause (so all documents are being retrieved and the filter is being done in memory). If I copy/paste the code inline for both dates (instead of calling the method twice) then the WHERE clause for the both dates are included in the query.

Is there no way to add a WHERE condition to an IQueryable by passing a property in a Func which can be properly translated to SQL by Entity Framework?

Comment: Hmm, you *might* have to construct the Expression manually in this case.

Comment: Why even have a function in the first place?

Comment: @DavidG This is a simplified version of my code. The method does more than what I've shown and the "Where" is much more detailed. The filter will do the same for each date and I would like to avoid copy/pasting the logic for each date.

Comment: The part `var query = dbContext.Documents();` is interesting.  Do you have a `Documents()` method in your DbContext?

Comment: @Brad I was writing the code from memory, I couldn't remember if the tables were properties. Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the question, now that I have code in front of me.

Answer (score 4):

EF is unable to understand your query, so it breaks and executes `WHERE` clause in memory.

The solution is creating dynamic expressions.

```
var query = dbContext.Documents.AsQueryable();

query = FilterDocumentsByDate(query, x => x.CreatedDate.Year);
query = FilterDocumentsByDate(query, x => x.SubmittedDate.Year);

private IQueryable<Document> FilterDocumentsByDate(IQueryable<Document> query, Expression<Func<Document, int>> expression)
{
    var parameter = expression.Parameters.FirstOrDefault();
    Expression comparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(expression.Body, Expression.Constant(2000));
    Expression<Func<Document, bool>> exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Document, bool>>(comparisonExpression, parameter);

    query = query.Where(exp);
    return query;
}
```

I am sorry, I haven't run this myself, but this should create WHERE statement. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Jaliya, I'll try this out and get back to you.

Comment: It will work. Except for small this that above does equality comparison rather than `>`